# Como saber se o dispositivo é Smathphone ou Tablet e/ou se é capaz de enviar SMS?

Tags: android, sms

Desenvolvi uma aplicação que é capaz de enviar um SMS com alguma informação apenas com um toque num botão, mas uma questão que me preocupa é os dispostivos que não tem capacidade de enviar SMS, tipo tablet's sem cartão SIM.

Existe alguma forma de eu conseguir validar esta situação? Saber se existe cartão SIM presente?

Answer (score 3):

Use a classe [TelephonyManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html).

Através do método [getPhoneType()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getPhoneType()) pode saber se é telefone e o seu tipo.

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
if(telephonyManager.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE){
    //não é telefone
}
```

Se for telefone, pode saber o estado do SIM recorrendo ao método [getSimState()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSimState()).

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
int phoneType = telephonyManager.getPhoneType();
if(phoneType == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE){
    //não é telefone
}else if(phoneType == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM){
    if(telephonyManager.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY){
        //Tem SIM e está pronto a usar
    }
}
```

Veja a documentação para os possíveis valores retornados por [getPhoneType()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getPhoneType()) e [getSimState()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSimState()).